# Laravel keep track of quantity for different models

Tags: laravel

I'm building a farm management application with Laravel with the following tables

```
products
  id
  trade_name
  state
  category_id

equipment
  id
  name
  type
```

`Product` is a chemical product and `Equipment` can either be a tractor or an implement

I want to keep track of quantity in both products and tractors

For products, quantity can be in litres or kilograms (depends on the state of the product)

For tractors I want to keep track of quantity of fuel

For that I'm thinking of creating a new `stocks` table with the following columns

```
stocks
  id
  stockable_id
  stockable_type
  quantity
```

The thing is I only have one warehouse which means creating a stocks tables doesn't really make sense but if I choose not to do it I'll have to add a `quantity` columns for both `products` and `equipment`

I'm lost with which approach I'd go with and I'd be happy to hear more from you guys

Comment: You can define a table where you can save attributes of product like quantity , product option and etc. Like 

product_attributes
id , product_id, scale|type , quantity, quantity availble, in stock check or not

Comment: That doesn't go for both products and equipment. If I do that I'll also have to create a equipment_attributes table

Comment: that's why i was suggesting to create a different table for just attributes and some column will be according to the data @O

Comment: @MuhammadShareyar can you have a look here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71546727/keep-track-of-quantity-and-some-columns-in-multiple-tables