# Keep track of quantity and some columns in multiple tables

Tags: laravel, database, schema, database-schema

I'm trying to build a farm management app with Laravel and I need help with my database schema. Here are some of my tables

users (id, name)
products (id, trade_name, state, category_id)
expenses (id, category_id)
activities (id, equipment_id)
equipment (id, name, type)

Equipment can either be a tractor or implement. For tractors I want to have the following columns `total_distance_traveled` and a `fuel_quantity`

Product can be fertilizers, Insecticide, Herbicides and their state can either be liquid or solid and I want to to keep track of quantity of my products as well (quantity is in liters or kilograms)

I'm not sure if it's a good idea to include the `total_distance_traveled` and `fuel_quantity` in the `equipment` table and a `quantity` column in the `products` table

I've thought of creating a new `stocks` table and have a `stockable_id`, and `stockable_type` but that would only work for quantity since it's kind of a common column between products and equipment tables

I'ld like to keep track of `total_distance_traveled`, `fuel_quantity` for the equipment table and `quantity` for products table. e.g. when the `total_distance_traveled` is changed I'd like to know when that happened so I can have logs of my activities over time

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `stock` table if you know that this table will only use for product and equipements:

```
id
stockable_id
stockable_type
quantity
total_distance_traveled // nullable as they have value only when item will be tractor,
fuel_quantity // nullable as they have value only when item will be tractor,
```

but for same table **or** if you think there can come other data too then a you can have a `json` column in which you can save extra attributes for specific item

```
id
stockable_id
stockable_type
quantity
sepecific_attributes  //json where you can save any additional values based on your product 
"{'total_distance_traveled':'100','fuel_quantity':20,'some_other_info':'value'}
```

Comment: Glad to help :) @Othmane